# Accessing additional fields for customized UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and working on my first app after running the official tutorial and reading other articles.

I am having problem accessing the additional field that I added for `User` model. I am not able to figure out the problem, any help/pointers will be much appreciated.

**Forms.py** (I have added the field `country` in the example code shown below)

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms

from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class RegisterUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    country = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RegisterUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_id = 'id-exampleForm'
            self.helper.form_class = 'blueForms'
            self.helper.form_method = 'post'
            self.helper.form_action = '.'
            self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2'
            )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterUserForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.country = self.cleaned_data["country"]
        print user.country
        if commit:
            print "saving user"
            user.save()
        return user
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import RegisterUserForm

class RegisterUserView(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterUserForm
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
    success_url = '/'
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import RegisterUserForm

class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = RegisterUserForm

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, NewUserAdmin)
```

**PROBLEM :**

In the `admin` app, I do not see the extra field. I even tried to access the `user` model using `shell` but could not get it. I am not able to understand what is wrong with my code. I tried using `print` statement in overriden save method and I can see it being executed.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all().last().country
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'country'
```

I tried debugging further and it looks like `save` is not saving the attribute, here is the method that I used

```
def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterUserForm,self).save(commit=False)
        user.country = self.cleaned_data["country"]
        print user.country
        if commit:
            print "saving user"
            user.save()
            print user.country
            print type(user)

            q = User.objects.all().last()
            print q.country. ------ ERROR ------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of mixing up forms and models. When you add a field to a form, that does not get automatically translated to a field on the model as well. The reverse holds true with `Model`s and `ModelForm`s. That is if you add a field to a Model, it can show up in a ModelForm without any real effort.

```
country = forms.CharField()
```

So what you are doing here is adding a field to a form.

What you need to do is to add it to your User model. But first you need to decide which approach you are going to take to [extends the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

One suggestion:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    country = models.CharField()
```

Then you need to `makemigrations` and `migrate`

Comment: Thanks :) , Now I understand the problem.

Comment: Glad to be of help